# Pyspark in Databricks: How to ingest data from odbc sql server to create a dataframe?

Tags: mysql, azure, pyspark, odbc, azure-databricks

in Azure databricks, need to connect to a table in odbc sql server and create a dataframe and create exactly the same table in databricks
I have already completed the below codes and I can see as attached. How to get the structured table, create the dataframe with the same info?
Could you please help with the scripts?

Below are what i have now:

```
pip install pyodbc
import pyodbc
server = 'XXXXXX-prod-db.database.chinacloudapi.cn'
database = 'database-ods'
username = 'os_reader'
password = 'P@ssword'
table = 'table_record'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(  
f'DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};'  
f'SERVER={server};'  
f'DATABASE={database};'  
f'UID={username};'  
f'PWD={password};'  
f'SELECT INTO={table}'  
)  
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
query = "SELECT * FROM " + table  
cursor.execute(query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
print(rows)
```

[image: what I can see now]

Comment: Is it mandatory to use ODBC? Your code is using python and not pyspark as the name of your question suggests and I don't think a single ODBC query will give the data and column names. Why not use JDBC which returns a spark dataframe with the data and column names?  https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-query-table-using-jdbc/

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/en/external-data/sql-server.html) for getting data.

In this, there are 2 options to get data:

1. Using **`sqlserver`**.
2. And using **`JDBC driver`**.

However, if you want to use **ODBC** itself, as @Anupam Chand mentioned, you will not get the column names.

But, you can achieve this using pandas:

```py
p_df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM student", cnxn)

s_df = spark.createDataFrame(p_df)
s_df.display()
```

Here, get data into a pandas dataframe and convert it into a spark dataframe.

`pd.read_sql_query("<query>", <connection_object>)`

`Output:`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged MySQL and title says SQL Server. If it's MySQL or SQL Server, they both support JDBC.

Spark [supports JDBC as a data source](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html).

TL;DR

```py
jdbcDF = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://XXXXXX-prod-db.database.chinacloudapi.cn") \
    .option("query", "SELECT * FROM table_record") \
    # .option("table", "table_record") \ # Same as select * from table
    .option("user", "os_reader") \
    .option("password", "P@ssword") \
    .load()

jdbcDF.show()
```

While running it you need ensure driver is installed on your cluster somehow. E.g.

```
spark-submit --packages com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:12.4.2.jre11 <your-script.py>
```